# Read data and click on stop button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem with my code.

Basically I read informations from a device (like acceleration, pressure, Magnetometer ).
They are a lot of data that are read every 20 ms.

At a certain point I want interrupt this reading, so I click a stop button.
And there, there is the problem. So the stop button doesn't work immediately (it looks like it wasn't clicked). So it remains completely still and after several seconds the action of the stop button starts.

What do you think this problem is due to?

```
async setupNotifications1(device) {
    var timeagm = 0
    var time = 0
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    device.monitorCharacteristicForService(service,this.AccGyrMg, (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error)
        {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...acc_dx] = [2, 4, 6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({acc_dx,array_acc_dx: [...state.array_acc_dx,[timeagm, acc_dx]]
        }));
        // code about the data that I read in the same way of acc (acceleration)
      }
    );

stopConnection() {
        console.log("start stopConnection");
    Actions.registerattivita(
        {
        array_acc_dx: this.state.array_acc_dx,
        array_acc_sx: this.state.array_acc_sx,
        array_gyr_dx: this.state.array_gyr_dx,
        array_gyr_sx: this.state.array_gyr_sx,
        array_mg_dx: this.state.array_mg_dx,
        array_mg_sx: this.state.array_mg_sx,
        array_pressure_sx: this.state.array_pressure_sx,
        array_pressure_dx: this.state.array_pressure_dx,
        id: this.props.id
      }
      )
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <View>
        // ..code about the graphics of the page
      <View style={styles.button}>

      <TouchableOpacity style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]} onPress={() => this.stopConnection()}>
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The page Actions.registerattivita is the page where I pass the variables to wrote the informations in the db. (If you need I can show also this page). But before to arrive in this page, are passed several seconds.

If I have not been clear I am ready to explain any part. Thank you very much for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```js
async stopConnection() {
        console.log("start stopConnection");
   await Actions.registerattivita(
        {
        array_acc_dx: this.state.array_acc_dx,
        array_acc_sx: this.state.array_acc_sx,
        array_gyr_dx: this.state.array_gyr_dx,
        array_gyr_sx: this.state.array_gyr_sx,
        array_mg_dx: this.state.array_mg_dx,
        array_mg_sx: this.state.array_mg_sx,
        array_pressure_sx: this.state.array_pressure_sx,
        array_pressure_dx: this.state.array_pressure_dx,
        id: this.props.id
      }
      )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I'll try :)  Do you think that this could be the problem??

Comment: This function is thought to be synchronous. So this will be the solution.